# How to escape single quote in flutter's localization file?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, escaping

I am creating dart's localisation file for my language by following flutter's [Adding support for a new language](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). Unfortunately the file seems not to accept the usual escape character (\) for single quote (') that is frequently used in my language (see the screenshot below). What is the properly way to escape the character (') in this localization file?

[Dart's localization file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqGAD.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of i see we can 2 solutions,

1. using "" quotes instaed ''

   ```
   String get modal => r"Tibo\'o";
   ```
2. changing your code like

   ```
   String get variableName => 'Tibo\'o';
   ```

Comment: Thank you @balaji-venkatraman The first solution removes the error.

Comment: I still do not have enough reputation to upvote, sorry. On the other hand the solution works but I haven't been able to make the whole localization for a new language work.

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing

Comment: I followed the instruction the official flutter's [Adding support for a new language](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-support-for-a-new-language) to create locale for my language (nia for Nias). However flutter throws exception invalid locale, as flutter looks in the database of supported locales instead of checking the local file created above (NiaMaterialLocalizations.delegate). Still no idea how to progress. I hope to find any example other people from non-supported locales had done.